# Passing test results from Postman Newman to Elasticsearch

Tags: api-testing, postman, newman

Any idea how to pass postman newman test results to Elasticsearch ?
I need to send every single test name, request url + test resut to elastic for kibana visualization. There's no native support from newman, can only save result as json file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use postman as a library , in this case the report is availble to you which you send to elastic search using elastic search API .

https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/#library

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the [Reporters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#reporters).

> Available reporters are: cli, json, junit, progress and emojitrain.

Since you are using AWS, check out [their guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automating-your-api-testing-with-aws-codebuild-aws-codepipeline-and-postman/) on this topic. It might not be exactly what you are trying to do but it does show the moving pieces.

> Automating your API testing with AWS CodeBuild, AWS CodePipeline, and Postman